# GRUB but no BIOS

Tags: 14.04

I have an Intel compute stick that came with Ubuntu 14.04, and I'm trying to access the BIOS so I can boot into a USB. The problem is that when pressing <kbd>f2</kbd>, <kbd>f7</kbd>, or <kbd>f10</kbd> none of them lead into the BIOS and instead go into GRUB. How can I access the bios from GRUB or boot into a USB from GRUB?

I've tried everything, including pressing <kbd>f7</kbd> or <kbd>f2</kbd> to update the BIOS, but that requires accessing the BIOS in the first place which I can't do. Intel provides information that pertains to the Windows model but doesn't really work for the Ubuntu model.

Comment: I did, and they reccomended pressing f7 to update the bios, but either it goes into ubuntu (when resetting my pc grub doesn't even load) or goes into grub. Perhaps the bios is somehow locked out of my compute stick so only Grub can load?

Comment: All of the methods require the f7 function or the f2 function, and all of those lead me to boot into GRUB unfortunately.... Another one requiring F4 show a menu that my intel compute stick doesn't have, therefore when pressing F4 nothing happens

Comment: Please edit the question to include all that information.

Comment: Did you try the `f12` key and did you check with your manufacturer to find how it is done?

Comment: Yes I did, nothing works... Can I erase the partion and write the bootable usb to it?